# ListView Error while using the "cacheExtent: double.infinity" in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-ios

To improve the performance I used cacheExtent: double.infinity in Listview. but in ios an error popup up. how to fix this error and why this error is poping?

code :

```
ListView.separated(
        cacheExtent: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
        itemCount: 200,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return _buildItem();
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider(
            color: AppColors.app_list_divider,
          );
        },
      )
```

Error :

*flutter: [2022-02-16 16:39:40.239153 | Catcher | FINE] Error: ''package:flutter/src/semantics/semantics.dart': Failed assertion: line 1592 pos 12: 'value.isFinite': SemanticsNode#60(Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), tags: [RenderViewport.twoPane], invisible) (with null) tried to set a non-finite rect.' has been skipped to due to duplication occurence within 3000 ms.*

Comment: There is a [`defaultCacheExtent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderAbstractViewport/defaultCacheExtent-constant.html) value when nothing is provided. It wouldn't be required much even with 100's of data in list view (at least it was smooth me). You could have a finite value. View [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderViewportBase/cacheExtent.html) for understanding it more. Making the cache to infinite might take up too much space which might actually not be needed. You can also file an issue in GitHub for what you are facing.

Comment: I am using the images in listview which doesn't cache. if I scroll the listview it will again trigger the image view URL and load it. and lots of widgets rebuild happened when I didn't use the cacheExtent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem today. Instead of using `double.infinity`, try to use `double.maxFinite`, like this:

```
ListView.separated(
  cacheExtent: double.maxFinite,
  ...
);
```

According to the docs, this are the values behind them:

```
static const double nan = 0.0 / 0.0;
static const double infinity = 1.0 / 0.0;
static const double negativeInfinity = -infinity;
static const double minPositive = 5e-324;
static const double maxFinite = 1.7976931348623157e+308;
```

It worked for me, hope it will work for you :)